# turn a sheaf $ F $ into a cosimplicial sheaf via Godement construction

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

let $  X  $ be a topological space and   $  F $  a sheaf   on  $  X $.  Let    $  X_{\text{disc}}  $  be the set  $  X   $  but now with the discrete topology.

[One possible way](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godement_resolution)  to associate to  $  F  $ the Godement sheaf  $  \operatorname{Gode}  $(the "Godement construction")  is given as follows:

Let  $  p: X_{\text{disc}} \to X     $     be the obviously continuous map induced by the identity. It induces adjoint direct and inverse image functors
$   p_{*} $ and    $   p^{-1}  $.   Then  $  \operatorname{Gode}(F) := p_{*}\circ p^{-1}(F)    $ . It's known that $   p_{*} $  and    $   p^{-1}  $ are adjoint functors and therefore the above functor $  p_{*}\circ p^{-1} $  regarded as endofunctor on the the category of sheaves on   $  X $     induces an associated monad on the category of sheaves on  $  X $
.

Next there is claimed that using this monad there is a way to turn a sheaf
$ F  $  into a coaugmented cosimplicial sheaf.

Question: how this construction turning  $  F  $ into a coaugmented cosimplicial sheaf works in detail?

Comment: It is called the [(co)bar construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bar+construction).